# An integral converges or diverges

Tags: integration, analysis

I have problems judging whether the integral
$$
\iint_{x\ +\ y\ \ge\ 1}
\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\sin\left(y\right)}{\left(x + y\right)^{p}}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$
converges or not. I've tried to transform it to $$
\frac{1}{2}\iint_{u\ \ge\ 1,\ v\ \in\ R}
\frac{\cos\left(v\right) - \cos\left(u\right)}{u^{p}}
\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v
$$
with $u=x+y,v=x-y$. But I failed to deal with this since I thought the second part of above fomula tends to $+\infty$ with each $u$ fixed.

Could anyone help $?$.

Comment: Do we know anything about the value of $p$?  Also, consider the bound
$$
\left| \int \int_{x + y \geq 1} {\sin x \sin y \over (x+ y)^p}  dx dy \right| 
\leq
\int \int_{x + y \geq 1} {1 \over |x + y|^p}  dx dy.
$$
This might be a start.

Comment: @R, not yet since we want to discuss the property due to different $p$s

Comment: Ok, consider first a simpler problem: the integral
$$
\int_{x \geq 1} {dx \over x^p}
$$
for different $p$'s.